Consumer seek resetting to latest intermediately
we are having a consumer logic as below. We are trying to consume multiple messages at a time , with a limitation of one message per partition.
 void consumerMessage(){
 while (!consumerService.isStopped(topic, server)) {
                processBatch(consumer,connection,topic,server);
            }}

}

 private void processBatch(Consumer<String, String> consumer, Connection connection, String topic,String server) throws Exception {
        Instant pollStartTime = Instant.now();
        Map<String,List<Integer>> topicPartitionMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> partitionOffsetMap = new HashMap<>();
        boolean isSuccess;
        int messageCount = 0;
        while (Duration.between(pollStartTime, Instant.now()).compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(MAX_POLL_DURATION)) < 0 && MAX_BATCH_SIZE > messageCount) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(10000);
            if (consumerRecords.isEmpty()) {
                continue; // Skip the iteration if there are no records
            }
            List<Integer> consumedPartition;
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : consumerRecords) {
                if (topicPartitionMap.containsKey(record.topic()) && topicPartitionMap.get(record.topic()).contains(record.partition())) {
                    continue;
                }
                consumedPartition = topicPartitionMap.containsKey(record.topic()) ? topicPartitionMap.get(record.topic()):new ArrayList<>();
                messages.add(objectMapper.readValue(record.value(), X.class));
                messageCount++;
                consumedPartition.add(record.partition());
                topicPartitionMap.put(record.topic(),consumedPartition);
                partitionOffsetMap.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                        new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset()+1, "processed"));
                log.info("partition {}, offset{} , topic {}",record.partition(),record.offset(),record.topic());
                
            }
        }
        if (messageCount > 0) {
            isSuccess= upload(messages,connection,topic,server);
            if(isSuccess) {
                log.info("Consumer commit for topic  {} and size {}",topic,messages.size());
                consumer.commitSync(partitionOffsetMap);
                resetOffset(partitionOffsetMap,consumer,0);
            }else{
                resetOffset(partitionOffsetMap,consumer,-1);
            }
        } else {
            log.info("No messages received in the last 1 minute.");
        }
    }



private void resetOffset(Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> partitionOffsetMap, Consumer<String, String> consumer,int offsetAddition){
        Set<TopicPartition> partitions = partitionOffsetMap.keySet();
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);

        for (Map.Entry<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> entry : partitionOffsetMap.entrySet()) {
            TopicPartition partition = entry.getKey();
            OffsetAndMetadata minOffset = entry.getValue();
            long newOffset = minOffset.offset() + offsetAddition;
            long lastOffset = endOffsets.get(partition);
            log.info("consumer manifest partition -{} seek to--- {} and end is {}",partition,newOffset,lastOffset);
            if(lastOffset>=newOffset) consumer.seek(partition, newOffset);
        }
    }

At times, post successful message consumption the seek pointer is moving to latest message although the seek log prints correct in logs.
Am I doing something wrong here ?

Why are you seeking at all?

The poll can seek to offset in a partition that I have not processed yet, so I am resetting it back to correct position

Polling happens after subscribing to a seeked position and polling defaults to read 500 records at once

Also, you're not actually using Spring Kafka here

@OneCricketeer Sorry for using spring-Kafka tab, I understand that poll fetches multiple records. I am processing/committing messages once every 1 minute, with a limit of one message per partition. During this 1 minute, various polls can be invoked, and the seek pointer can differ from what I am committing after a minute.
Either I initiate the consumer again or seek to correct the value. Now, seeking is working, but at times, it moves to the latest offset. That is the concern I have raised.

Please share where you've set up the consumer config.
